# Extracting data from text log file advice

Tags: php

I would like an advice on best approach on this task.

I have a text log file holding data from a gps, this is the format:

```
time,lat,lon,elevation,accuracy,bearing,speed

2014-07-08T12:56:52Z,56.187344,10.192660,116.400024,5.000000,285.000000,1.063350

2014-07-08T12:56:58Z,56.187299,10.192754,113.799988,5.000000,161.000000,3.753000

2014-07-08T12:57:07Z,56.186922,10.193048,129.200012,5.000000,159.000000,5.254200

2014-07-08T12:57:13Z,56.186694,10.193133,109.799988,5.000000,152.000000,3.878100

2014-07-08T12:57:16Z,56.186745,10.193304,142.900024,5.000000,149.000000,3.940650

2014-07-08T12:57:20Z,56.186448,10.193417,118.700012,5.000000,154.000000,2.376900

2014-07-08T12:57:27Z,56.186492,10.193820,131.299988,5.000000,65.000000,5.379300
```

I need to find the line where the speed exceeds a certain value, then get the time from that line, then scroll trough the lines and find the line where the speed is below this value, get the time and write these 2 time values into my database.

This has to be an automated task, so I assume that a cron PHP script could do the job.

Best regards Thomas

Comment: Are you looking for advice or for someone to solve the problem for you? You will have to show us that you have put some effort into solving it yourself.

Comment: I'll try to solve it myself, just need advice on the best way to go. Just trying to be specifik about the task.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that there is no special advice needed but wanting someone to code your problem - I will try to put you in the right direction. I've written easy to understand code where you can build on (untested)...

```
<?php
// Setup.
$pathGpsFile = 'gps.log';
$speedThreshold = 5;

//
// Execution.
//
if(!file_exists($pathGpsFile)) {
    die('File "'. $pathGpsFile .'" does not exist.');
}

// Read entries into array.
$gpsEntries = file($pathGpsFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Loop through entries.
$lineCount = 0;
$currentDifferences = array();
$currentDifference = array();

foreach($gpsEntries as $gpsEntry) {
    // Skip head.
    if($lineCount == 0) {
        $lineCount++;
        continue;
    }

    // Extract values from gps entry.
    list($time, $lat, $lon, $elevation, $accuracy, $bearing, $speed) = explode(',', $gpsEntry);

    // Check if there is currently a difference monitored.
    if(count($currentDifference) == 1) {
        if($speed < $speedThreshold) {
            $currentDifference[] = $gpsEntry;
        }

        // Add to differences list.
        $currentDifferences[] = $currentDifference;

        // Reset current difference.
        $currentDifference = array();
    } else {
        if($speed > $speedThreshold) {
            $currentDifference[] = $gpsEntry;
        }
    }

    // Increase line count.
    $lineCount++;
}

// Check output.
var_dump($currentDifferences);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I was only asking for advice wether it was a bad idea to go by PHP. Thomas

Comment: Well... I didn't find that sentence in the question - that you're just asking wether or not is a good idea. Nontheless: it's difficult to say. It is possible to use php - but there might be better options. It depends how many imports you plan. It might be better to use a low-level language like C/C++.